# Try except finally - Is EMPTY try except finally valid in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Is it okay to have empty try except finally block in python, something like this,

```
try:
    #nothing here,
except:
    #nothing here as well,
finally:
    #nothing here too.
```

Comment: Just run your (pointless) code.

Comment: Your blocks are not completely empty--each has a comment. Do you mean completely empty, containing only comments, containing only the `pass` statement, or something else? And why don't you just try each and see what happens?

Comment: @RoryDaulton The parser ignores comments; they cannot act as statements where at least one is required.

Comment: thank you for asking, i was having trouble doing nothing on error (with a comment only finally) and this comes up for "python empty finally"

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use `pass` to pass a block:

```
try:
    pass
except:
    pass
finally:
    pass
```

More examples:

```
def a():
    pass

while True:
    pass

for i in range(10):
    pass
...
```

Comment: The time literally passes in the while loop.